# if and else don't assign false

Tags: php, if-statement

I have simple code which is something like this:

```
$options = new Options();
$page = new Pages();
if($page->page_limit() <= $options->pageno) {
    $page->userid = $user_details->userid;
    $page->date_of_pub = $_POST['date_of_pub'];
    $resultss=$page->page_create();

}
else {
    $resultss=false;
}
```

Then at bottom I am putting a condition

```
if(isset($resultss) && isset($resultss) == true) {
    echo $alert->SuccessMsg("Page created successfully!");
}
if(isset($resultss) && isset($resultss) == false) {
    echo $alert->ErrorMsg("You Have Been Reached to your maximum page limit");
}
```

Instead of printing error value even I have set the value of `$result = false` is shows success message, means its showing `$resultss = true` statement.

Suggest something. This is so strange. I got the answer thank you so much :)

**One more thing.**

can you please tell me how can I get rid of this `" echo $alert->ErrorMsg"` this is so annoying for all the class and functions. I want to make it a single word.

Comment: Directly check `($resultss==true)` `isset($resultss)` will be true even if `$resultss` is false.

Comment: mmm what's this? `if(isset($resultss) && !isset($resultss)) {`. Its like saying if its morning and its not morning then do so n so

Comment: You really don't need to check if the variables are set. Just do `if ($resultss) { Do Stuff } else { Do Other Stuff }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the same twice:

```
isset($resultss) && isset($resultss)==true
```

You should do:

```
isset($ressults) && $ressults == true
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your logic with `isset()`. This:

```
if(isset($resultss) && isset($resultss)==true){echo $alert->SuccessMsg("Page created successfully!");}
if(isset($resultss) && isset($resultss)==false){echo $alert->ErrorMsg("You Have Been Reached to your maximum page limit");}
```

Should be

```
if(isset($resultss) && $resultss == true){echo $alert->SuccessMsg("Page created successfully!");}
if(isset($resultss) && $resultss ===false){echo $alert->ErrorMsg("You Have Been Reached to your maximum page limit");}
```

In your existing code, the second `isset()` in each statement is incorrect. In the first one, it is redundant, and you are asking the same thing as `if(isset($resultss) && isset($resultss))`, which is always true. In the second one, `isset($resultss) && isset($resultss)==false` could never be true. It's like `true && false`.

Comment: Thank you it worked very fine. I made a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Change your IF conditions to:

```
if(isset($resultss) && $resultss == true)
```

`isset(x)` and `isset(x) == true` bacially mean the same. What you want is to match two conditions:
the variable IS SET and IT IS EQUAL TO TRUE.

Since I'm not sure what the value might be I'd suggest using these confitions:

```
if(isset($resultss) && $resultss !== false)    //the value is set and it is NOT set to false
```

AND

```
if(isset($resultss) && $resultss === false)    //the value is set to false
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i get rid of this " echo $alert->ErrorMsg" this is so annoying for all the class and functions. I want to make it a single word.

Comment: If I get it right you think it's too long. You can define your own function. Something like this: function showErr($str) { $alert = new AlertClass(); $alert->ErrorMsg($str); } and then call it instead of direct object method like this: showErr('Your error message');

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to check if the variables are set, since you are setting it in both branches of the if/else. Just do:

```
if ($resultss) {
     echo $alert->SuccessMsg("Page created successfully!");
} else {
    echo $alert->ErrorMsg("You Have Been Reached to your maximum page limit");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting it to false as default?

```
$options = new Options();
$page = new Pages();
$resultss = false;
if($page->page_limit() <= $options->pageno){
    $page->userid = $user_details->userid;
    $page->date_of_pub = $_POST['date_of_pub'];
    $resultss = $page->page_create();
}
```

Comment: The issue he's having is with the if conditions, not the assignment logic.

Comment: Yes there i was again checking with isset() which was wrong. But now problem is solvled. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: So I see. That's my own fault for not reading your code properly haha!